# What is the syntax to add hours to a datetime value?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, date

I have a trigger that goes like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trCreatedDate ON [LasMTest]

FOR INSERT 

AS

UPDATE [LasMTest] SET [LasMTest].Created=getdate()

FROM [LasMTest] INNER JOIN Inserted ON [LasMTest].[ID]= Inserted.[ID]

GO
```

What is the syntax to add 8 hours to the current datetime `[LasMTest].Created=getdate()`?

Comment: Have you consulted [the manual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

DATEADD will help you accomplish this, as follows:

```
[LasMTest].Created = DATEADD(hh, 8, GETDATE())
```

Comment: +1 but I highly recommend against lazy shorthand. Try out `SELECT DATEPART(y, GETDATE());` to see why. If you mean `HOUR`, just type `HOUR` instead of this fancy `hh` nonsense.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Thank you for your comment.  I personally am content with the use of 'hh' as I know what it represents but I do take your point.

Comment: What you do in your own code is your business/problem/etc. I'm suggesting what you should do when writing example code for others to learn from.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you need a trigger for this operation? It would be better to use default constraint.
You can even use dateadd() in it:

```
create table _TEst (
z int, 
x datetime default dateadd(hour,3,getdate() )
)
insert into _TEst(z) select 1 as z
select * from _test
```

Comment: +1 agreed, there is no need for a trigger to handle something so trivial.

Comment: Actually yes, I forgot I had actually changed that in the meantime. It is down as a constraint. I am using the trigger for LastUpdated instead.